# How to merge two data tables with same names but they are case sensitive?

Tags: c#, datatable

I am getting dynamic data from two sources. The column names are same but have different casing. While merging data tables it will create duplicate columns. I want to merge with same columns, regardless of the casing.

Code:

```
dataTable1.merge(dataTable2);
```

My column names in dataTable1 are:

```
Title
filePath
```

My column names in dataTable2 are:

```
title
FilePath
```

It should consider these two columns as identical.

MyCode:

```
    public void TestOnMergeDataTables()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Order");
        DataColumn dc = dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "pramod");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "ravi");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "deepak");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "kiran");
        dt.Rows.Add(5, "madhu");

        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Order");
        DataColumn dc2 = dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt2.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
        dt2.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(String));

        dt2.Rows.Add(6, "ashu", "Gen");
        dt2.Rows.Add(7, "rudra", "Gen");
        dt2.Rows.Add(8, "kavita", "Gen");
        dt2.Rows.Add(9, "suman", "Gen");
        dt2.Rows.Add(10, "lakshman", "Gen");

        dt.Merge(dt2,true);
    }
```

Result:
[Output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtnNm.png)

it should treat Name , name columns as same column

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Please post your attempts at trying to solve this problem. As it stands, your question is asking us to create something that does not yet exist, as opposed to fixing something that doesn't work. SO only focuses on the latter, whereas the former kind of question ends up being closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way can be using linq. (This won't remove duplicates present in the columns). For removing duplicates, you have to use GroupBy.

```
var mergedTable = dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(row => new { Key = dataRow["Title"], Row = dataRow })
                 .Union(dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(row => new { Key = dataRow["title"], Row = dataRow }))
                 .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I don't know the column names

Comment: can you provide a minimum reproducible example?